# Finding maxima of a multivariable function

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

I would like to find the maxima of this function:
$$\frac{a_1x}{a_1+KV}+\frac{a_2x}{a_2+KV}+\frac{a_1a_2x}{(a_1+KV)(a_2+KV)}+\frac{a_3x}{a_3+KV}+\frac{a_2a_3x}{(a_2+KV)(a_3+KV)}+\frac{a_1a_2a_3x}{(a_1+KV)(a_2+KV)(a_3+KV)}+...+\frac{a_nx}{a_n+KV}+\frac{a_1a_2a_3...a_nx}{(a_1+KV)(a_2+KV)(a_3+KV)...(a_n+KV)}$$
Given $a_1+a_2+...+a_n=V'$ where $x, K, V, V'$ are constants.
For convenience, I've converted the series into a simpler form
$$x\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{p=i}^j\frac{a_p}{a_p+KV}$$
I can't think of any inequality that can suit this series at the moment. If the answer is trivial enough, I would like anyone to provide tips rather than the complete answer.

Comment: Have you attempted to consider the particular cases $n=2$ and $n=2$ ?

Comment: 1) Your $j$ index must vary between $i+1$ and $n$. 2) A slight simplification can be given by expressing your fraction under the form $f(a_p)$ where $f(x):=1/(1+KV/x))$.

Comment: Could you give a little context for this question which surely hasn't a "trivial" answer as you are fearing... ?

Comment: Please react to my comments...

Comment: @JeanMarie This is because the series is not considered cyclic and most of the inequalities in contest math are cyclic.